# Trying to display a ProgressDialog in AsyncTask executed in a MapActivity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a MapActivity that has code similar to this in onCreate():

```
if(...) {
    ...
    new FirstAsyncTask(id, this).execute((Object[]) null);
    ...
} else {
    ...
    myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        new SecondAsyncTask(lat, lon, ActivityName.this).execute((Object[]) null);
    }
    ...
}
```

The FirstAsyncTask and SecondAsyncTask both do different things, but both of them show a ProgressDialog like so:

```
public FirstAsyncTask(long id, Context context) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    ...
    progressDialog.show();
}

protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    ...
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    ...
}
```

This is working with FirstAsyncTask, but no matter what I change in the call to SecondAsyncTask it always fails with this error: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(). I have tried setting the context parameter to "this", "ActivityName.this", getApplicationContext(), and getBaseContext().

I'm still pretty new to Android so this idea of a "context" is confusing me. I'm even more confused that FirstAsyncTask works but SecondAsyncTask doesn't. I've seen this error mentioned a lot in other questions but none of the answers seem to work. Any ideas?

EDIT: The exception is being thrown when the ProgressDialog is being initialized in the SecondAsyncTask's constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
    new SecondAsyncTask(lat, lon, ActivityName.this).execute((Object[]) null);
}
```

SecondAsyncTask is being constructed on a newly spawned thread. not the UI thread.

Create the one progressDialog in the activity. And then access the Activity's progressDialog from the Asynctasks.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    onCreate(...){
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog();
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<...> {
        ...
        onPreExecute(...){
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        onPostExecute(...){
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<...> {
        ...
        onPreExecute(...){
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        onPostExecute(...){
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Do not attempt to perform progressDialog.dismiss() from the doInBackground, instead put it in postExecute which is running in the UI thread.

You'll want to set up flags once all this is working so that you only dismiss the progressdialog once both tasks are complete.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain why one of them is working fine and the other is not.

Comment: It's because you are constructing the progressdialog on a different thread to the UI thread. You are constructing it within the constructor of the secondasynctask which is spawning on a new thread.

Comment: These AsyncTasks are reused across several activities in the app. They're not declared in just this activity. The ProgressDialog is only having a problem in this one instance. Is moving the dialog outside of the AsyncTask the only workaround?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't say. But you can leave the asynctasks where they are, just declare local private class extensions and override preExecute and postExecute with any activity specific stuff, ie. the progressdialogs.

Comment: so private class PrivateAsyncTask1 extends MyAsyncTask where MyAsyncTask is declared seperately. And PrivateAsyncTask1 only overrides (and calls super) onPreExecute and onPostExecute to handle the progressdialog stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Write your dialogue dismiss code inside `onPostExecute()` method it will run the code in the UI thread

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Write your AsyncTask class this way:

```
private class FirstAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog myDialog = null;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivityClass.this, "",
                "Loading Data...");
return;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
//Your code which you want to run in background
return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
myDialog.dismiss();
return;
}
}
```

above code works if you have defined the AsyncTask class as inner class of the Activity. If your AsyncTask class is defined as a seperate class then you have to pass the context of the activity to its constructor

```
ProgressDialog myDialog = null;
Context context;
public FirstAsyncTask (Context context) {
    this.context = context;     
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "",
            "Loading Data...");
return;
}
```

Comment: See edits. Should have mentioned this before. The problem is with initializing the ProgressDialog in the constructor.